# How to get text from image

Tags: python, ocr

I want to read the text from an image.

I use `pytesseract` in Python.

Here is my code:

```py
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image = Image.open(r'a.jpg')
image.resize((150, 50),Image.ANTIALIAS).save("pic.jpg")
image = Image.open("pic.jpg")
captcha = pytesseract.image_to_string(image).replace(" ", "").replace("-", "").replace("$", "")
```

[image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D7JZ7oYQyH68oqZljbl4i4G-esSnpVe7/view?usp=sharing)

However, it returns empty string.

What should be the correct way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i agree with @Jon Betts

1. tesseract is not very strong in OCR, only good in binary cases with right settings
2. CAPTCHAs ment to fool OCRs!

but if you really need to do it, you need to come up with the manual procedure for it,

i created the code below specifically for the type of CAPTCHAs that you gave (but its completely rigid and is not generalized/optimized for all cases)

**psudo code**

1. apply median blur
2. apply a threshold to get Blue colors only (binary image output from this stage)
3. apply opening to reduce small white pixels in binary image
4. give the image to tesseract with options:

   - limited whitelist of output chars
   - OEM 3 : tesseract + cube
   - PSM 8 : one word per image

**Code**

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
import cv2


img = cv2.imread('a.jpg')
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 3)
# extract blue parts
img2 = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8)
cond = np.bitwise_and(img[:, :, 0] >= 100, img[:, :, 2] < 100)
img2[np.where(cond)] = 255
img = img2
# delete the noise
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (3, 3))
img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

str1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(img),
                                       config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=abcedfghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz0123456789 -oem 3 -psm 8')

cv2.imwrite("frame.png", img)
print(str1)
```

**output**

```
f2e4
```

[image]

[image](https://pasteboard.co/IoKaEmS.png)

in order to see full options of tesseract, type the following command `tesseract --help-extra` or refere to [this_link](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc)

Comment: I got the error : `pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, "Error, unknown command line argument '-psm'")`

Comment: Comment the tesseract line and get the image output, try tesseract using the command line/terminal, if you're still getting the error, the tesseract setup has a problem

Answer (score 3):

Tesseract is intended for performing OCR on text documents. In my experience it's good but a bit patchy even with very clean data.

In this case it appears you are trying to solve a CAPTCHA which is specifically designed to defeat OCR software. **It's very likely you cannot use Tesseract to solve this issue**, because:

- It's not really designed for that
- The scenario is adversarial:

  - **The example is specifically designed to prevent what you are trying to do**
  - If you could get it to work, the other party would likely change it to break again

If you want to proceed I would suggest:

- Working on cleaning up the image before attempting to process it (can you get a nice readable black and white image?)
- Train your own recognition network using a lot of examples